# Mobile-friendly menu problems

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

Say you have a 10 top-level categories(links) for the main menu navigation of the website. and each of them(each category) have between 2-3 to 8-10 sub-categories(links).

Now, for the desktop view there's lots of options to play. From drop-down menu to showing sub-categories only at the relevant category page(only category1-page will include sub-categories of the category1 etc).

But, while with the desktop version there's at least couple of ways to play around, for mobile there's none. I can't think for even one efficient and design-friendly(usability-friendly) way to place 30-100 links on the page. I diffidently don't want to use large amount of links in the hamburger icon-navigation.

I'm asking you to help me understand of how this should be done properly on the mobile devices. Perhaps there's some best practices or anything that may help. I'm sure there's lots of people will be facing this. Thanks

Comment: make the menu container scrollable.

Comment: yeah, but man... imagine this for a 100 links. it's just not right to do. I thought about accordion-style, but nothing else is coming to my mind

Comment: you can do both. Only the accordion will not be sufficient as the screen size of the device is limited and since it's a menu you need to make it available to the user anyhow

Comment: well yeah, it's sure thing it's should be scrollable... out of question.